# Laravel Migration rename nullable field workaround?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, doctrine-orm, laravel-5.4

It appear there is a breaking change in mariadb 10.2.7 if you try to rename a field nullable datetime column and you will get an error if you run a migration:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'due_date' (SQL: ALTER TABLE test
   CHANGE dueDate due_date DATETIME DEFAULT 'NULL')
```

Create migration:

```
class CreateTestTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('test', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->dateTime('dueDate')->nullable();
        });
    }
}
```

Create a second migration to rename the column:

```
class RenameColumn extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('test', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->renameColumn('dueDate', 'due_date');
        });
    }
}
```

Is there a workaround to get this to work?

According to doctrine/dbal [issue](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/pull/2825):

> In order to allow expressions as default values and distinguish them
>   from literals, Mariadb now quotes default values in
>   information_schema.column table. This changes brings a lot of
>   incompatibilities between the (Oracle-)Mysql/MariaDB platforms.
>
> Instead of creating a specific SchemaManager for MariaDB, the solution
>   taken in this P/R is to map the introduced changes in the current
>   MySQLSchemaManager (method: getMariaDb1027ColumnDefault()).
>
> From MariaDB 10.2.7, information schema changes includes:
>
> NULL is now quoted as 'NULL' (exception when colum default is not
>   nullable and no default provided: NULL is saved in
>   information_schema), EDIT: see an exception
>   https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-14053 String defaults are quoted
>   (To save the string 'NULL', set the default as ''NULL''). Escaping:
>   "'" are silently changed to "''" in information schema. This should
>   not have impact unless you manually escaped default values with "'" in
>   your models (schema diff). See also point 5. Default literals values
>   must be quoted which brings support for automatic CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
>   CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_TIME defaults are silently changed to
>   'current_timestamp()', 'currdate()', 'currtime()'. To prevent schema
>   diff, they are mapped back to their original values.

Comment: Have you tried `$table->renameColumn('dueDate', 'due_date')->nullable()`?

Comment: Have you tried making the column non-nullable, renaming, and then making it nullable again? `$table->nullable(false)->change()`

Answer (score 1):

You could try this approach:

Create new column and run query to copy values from your old column to your new column

```
class RenameColumn extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('test', function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->dateTime('due_date')->nullable();
        });

        // copy values from column 'dueDate' to 'due_date'
        // DB::update returns number of affected rows
        DB::update('UPDATE `test` SET due_date = dueDate');

        Schema::table('test', function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->dropColumn('dueDate');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('test', function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->dateTime('dueDate')->nullable();
        });

        DB::update('UPDATE `test` SET dueDate = due_date');

        Schema::table('test', function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->dropColumn('due_date');
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the provided solutions work I prefer a simpler approach:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('test', function (Blueprint $table) {
        DB::statement('ALTER TABLE `test` CHANGE `dueDate` `due_date` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL;');
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('test', function (Blueprint $table) {
        DB::statement('ALTER TABLE `test` CHANGE `dueDate` `due_date` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL;');
    });
}
```